# "order a helmet" - Why not "an"?

Tags: grammaticality

I've encountered the following sentence:

> order a helmet

Shouldn't it be "order an helmet" instead?

Comment: Why would you write 'an' before a word that starts with a consonant?

Comment: @DecapitatedSoul - It's *an honour* to receive your help. Shall we discuss it for *an hour*?

Comment: @nnnnnn, By 'consonant', I mean *consonant sound*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As a first approximation, "an" would be used if the initial "h" wasn't pronounced, as some variants of English do with "herb". In "helmet" the "h" is pronounced in most accents, so we use "a".

Of course being English it's never quite that simple - in "an hotel", which used to be common, the "h" is often clear. That has been known to apply to "herb" in British English too.

If, like me, you're from London (UK), you say be prone to dropping the "h". So speaking formally, I'd say "a helmet", but informally might say something more like "a nelmet"

Comment: The reason that _an hotel_ used to be considered correct, is that _hotel_ was thought of as a French word and pronounced with a silent 'h' as in French. As the 'h' is now always pronounced in standard English, _a_ is always used.

Comment: @KateBunting That's not true. I still hear some people using *an hotel* with a pronounced *h*. Just like I still hear people say *an historic moment* with a pronounced *h*. It seems to be more prevalent in the UK than the US. So "never" is a oversimplification.

Comment: @KateBunting I don't know if there's an element of hypercorrection, or what's going on, but there are definitely cases in British English in which both "n" and "h" are pronounced.   They're not common though

Comment: @KateBunting "As the 'h' is now always pronounced in standard English, a is always used." I am an 'an hotel' holdout. Maybe I got it from the BBC growing up in the 1950s and 60s.

Comment: Also an historic occasion, which I defend from accusations of affectation with this from Oxford: "the older form, with the silent h and the indefinite article an, is still encountered, especially among older speakers."

Comment: OK, all, you win. I said 'always' because I had checked several online dictionaries and found none that mentioned the silent 'h'.

Comment: @JasonBassford - "I still hear some people using an hotel with a pronounced h." I would never do this. An 'otel, an 'istoric occasion, an 'istorian, BUT a history book. For the avoidance of doubt, I don't speak with a London or Estuary accent.